Cancel current pipeline job "from within" in Azure ML sdk v2
I am porting a sdk v1 machine learning pipeline to SDK v2. We have a step which, under certain conditions, cancels the whole pipeline job (ie, the other steps won't run). Its code is like this:
from azureml.core import Run
from azureml.pipeline.core import PipelineRun

run = Run.get_context()
ws = run.experiment.workspace
pipeline_run = PipelineRun(run.experiment, run.parent.id)
if condition:
    pipeline_run.cancel()

I can't find a way to do something similar using Python SDK v2. And I don't want to mix v1 and v2 code. How could I do it? Any ideas?

Check the migration documentation frim v1 to v2 in azure docs

This didn't help either. Didn't find the info I need there.

Here is how you can cancel the job using sdk v2.
First create a client object using below code.
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, InteractiveBrowserCredential
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient

try:
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    # Check if given credential can get token successfully.
    credential.get_token("https://management.azure.com/.default")
except Exception as ex:
    # Fall back to InteractiveBrowserCredential in case DefaultAzureCredential not work
    credential = InteractiveBrowserCredential()


ml_client = MLClient(
    credential, subscription_id, resource_group, workspace
)

Next, cancel the job.
ml_client.jobs.begin_cancel(<pipeline_job.name or run_id>)

Either you get the job name from the object return after submitting the job like below
pipeline_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(
    pipeline_job, experiment_name="today"
)
pipeline_job.name


or
in the portal

Output:

Immediately it won't cancel, it will be Inprogress state later after some time the cancel request succeeds.

Unfortunately, my pipeline runs daily, on a scheduler. At some point one of the jobs checks whether the pipeline run must continue or be canceled. Since the pipeline runs unatended, I can't realy pass the job name or job id from "outside". It must be retrieved from within a child job...

I thought you have already retrieved  job name. From current run you need cancel the parent job right? I will check and update it.

please add the code you have created for v2 till now. the step you are running and where you are trying to cancel the job. is it in child job which is running currently or separate script where you will get the run context?
